# cannot access pdf using public url uploaded on cloudinary

Tags: http, pdf, cloudinary

I am trying to access pdf using public url uploaded on cloudinary however url request has been successfully completed but nothing showed.

Permission : Blocked for delivery shows in properties of pdf on cloudinary

Comment: PDFs are restricted by default for Free plan as explained here: https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/articles/360016480179-PDF-or-ZIP-files-appearing-in-Media-Library-but-download-URLs-return-an-error-. You can also contact them if you need to lift the restriction

Answer (score 8):

If you are on a free plan and need to deliver files in these formats, you can navigate to the Security tab of Settings in the Management Console and select to 'Allow delivery of PDF and ZIP files' or find it at the bottom.

Comment: "In our efforts to make sure no malicious files are distributed through Cloudinary, free customers can’t deliver files in the PDF format by default. Please contact support if you want to enable this feature for your account." See [Delivering PDF files](https://cloudinary.com/blog/uploading_managing_and_delivering_pdfs#delivering_pdf_files)

Comment: That blog post is older; the current documentation shows that it can be enabled via the settings page

Answer (score 2):

Based on a recent update to our security policies, we've restricted delivery on newly created Free accounts for PDFs and Archive files. Such files can still be uploaded, but the restriction is specifically on delivery.

For PDFs that are uploaded with `resource_type` - "image", as they support transformations, they can be converted to images and will be delivered - e.g. by using the `page` transformation (`pg_` in URLs) and setting the extension to jpg. -

in javascript we just need to replace extension to .jpg

```
 response?.data?.url.replace(".pdf", ".jpg")
```

[source](https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360008128779/comments/360001615099)